# Chart.js labels on chart line

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to implement charts to my web project, but having trouble to display labels with corresponding value over Chart Line ticks. I tried looking over documentation to implement it, but without success. I look also for samples, but i was unable to find example with chart labels.

Example:
[Example of my chart, where labels are missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xtX.png)

My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

const MainEfficiencyChart = (props) => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

    const data = {
      labels: props.labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Efficiency",
          borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
          data: props.data.efficiency,
          yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
          scales: { // Here i tried to add ticks labels
            ticks: {
              backdropColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
              display: true,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          label: "M/H Time",
          borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          data: props.data.time,
          yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
        },
        {
          label: "Operators",
          borderColor: "rgb(91,244,10)",
          data: props.data.operators,
          yAxisID: "y-axis-3",
        },
      ],
    };

    const options = {
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: "category",
          ticks: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
          },
        },
        "y-axis-1": {
          type: "linear",
          position: "left",
          ticks: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
          },
          grid: {
            color: "rgb(197,191,136)",
            borderDash: [5, 5],
          },
        },
        "y-axis-2": {
          type: "linear",
          position: "right",
          ticks: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
          },
        },
        "y-axis-3": {
          type: "linear",
          position: "left",
          ticks: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          labels: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: data,
      options: options,
    });

    return () => {
      myChart.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={chartRef} width="200" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainEfficiencyChart;
```

Comment: If there's only one label you want to display (or a few, haphazardly), you should use [chartjs-plugin-annotations](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/label.html); if you want to add labels associated with the points and values of the chart, you should use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/#table-of-contents)